# How should a question be closed if the answer is given in documentation?

Tags: discussion, questions, close-reasons, documentation

Since documentation is in public beta now, what close reason should be used for a question whose answer is given in an example of a topic in documentation? The example uses the same language/technology as the question demands.

Should this eventually get its own close reason linking to the example?

Answer (score 2):

The question would be at the mercy, then, of the interpretation and reaction of the closers; it becomes the SO equivalent of RTFM, disregarding that a person asking the question may need more than just a link to an example or there may be a subtle difference. Or, as I've seen in some cases, the closers did not read the question properly.

Instead, documentation should serve as a supplement to a good answer.